# handling events to multiple radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple radio button in my page with name ,"p1radio","p2radio","p3radio"..etc..When I click any of the radio button, I need a set of actions to be taken place.

html

```
<td><input type="radio" name="p1radio"/><

/td>
<td><input type="radio" name="p21radio"/></td>
<td><input type="radio" name="p31radio"/></td>
<td><input type="radio" name="p41radio"/></td>
```

Question:
Is there a way to write a generic event handler for all these radio buttons,since only the first 2 bytes - p1, p2...varies in these buttons...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like this :

```
function clickFunc(){};
var radios = ['p2','p3','p4'];
for(var i in radios) document.getElementById(radios[i]+'1radio').onclick = clickFunc;
```

Comment: but how can I trigger this function, when one of the radio button is triggered

Comment: How can I implement the same in Jquery..I tried this but not working...http://jsfiddle.net/MJ9qp/1/

Comment: Sadly I have no idea. I use pure JS only.